# When will money deduction happens for free trial auto renewal subscription?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, auto-renewable

I have a 1-month auto renewal product with 1-month free trial configured in my iTunes account. As per my understanding amount deduction should happen after the 1-month free trial end. But for users in production, money deduction happens right after subscription and even before free trial starts. Is this an expected scenario or can anyone please guide me?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Auto-renewable subscriptions give users access to content or services
>   from within your app on an ongoing basis. At the end of each
>   subscription duration, the subscription will automatically renew until
>   a user chooses to cancel it.
>
> Auto-renewable subscriptions provide a simple way to offer free trials
>   to users. When users sign up for a subscription with a free trial,
>   their subscription begins immediately but they won’t be billed until
>   the free trial period is over. How long a free trial can be depends on
>   the duration of the subscription offering. For example, a one-month
>   subscription cannot offer a free trial of longer than one month. For
>   more details on free trial durations, see [Subscription Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Appendices/InAppPurchaseProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013727-CH29-SW5).

Comment: But for my case I am charged with my subscription amount right after the subscription started and I presume next deduction will happen after 2 months including 1 month free trial and 1 month actual subscription period. Not sure if there is something am missing while configuring a product.

Comment: Background of the story: One customer has raised concern that money was remitted on subscription itself when he has free trial period available on subscribe button click itself.Cannot find any document saying about amount remittance.

Saw in the iTunes product configuration page this will be only done on free trial completion time.Need confirmation. Please share if any supported link or document on the same.